# F# CsvTypeProvider Not Reading Complete String

Tags: .net, f#, type-providers

I am trying to read the [movies.txt](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41undirected/movies.txt) using F# CsvTypeProvider using the below mentioned code :

```
type movies = CsvProvider<"../../movies.csv","/",InferRows=0,HasHeaders=false,IgnoreErrors=true,AssumeMissingValues=true,MissingValues="">
```

F# is inferring the type for movies type as : `FSharp.Data.Runtime.CsvFile<System.Tuple<string,string,string>>`
Due to this only the first three column values are being read. I understand that its not a uniform csv file i.e. every row is not having the same number of columns. I wanted to know if this file is right candidate or not for the CsvProvider. Also is there any other type provider which can parse the above mentioned file?

Sample Record

```
Akira (1988)/Louie, Detroit/Lindsay, Michael (II)/Martin, Dan (II)/Stone, Doug (I)/Blum, Steven Jay/Woren, Dan/Forest, Michael (I)/Wurst, Brad/Akimoto, Yôsuke/Cole, George C./Katô, Masayuki (I)/Prescott, Simon/Reynolds, Mike (I)/Held, Watney/Prince, Derek Stephen/Lembaw, Mike/Ôtake, Hiroshi/Lang, Lex/Kusao, Takeshi/Arakawa, Tarô/Bosch, Johnny Yong (I)/Strong, Sam (I)/Buckley, Ivan/Taggert, Jim/Hirano, Masato/Seth, Joshua/Sholder, Adam/Inagaki, Satoru/Sasaki, Nozomu/Buchholz, Bob/Joyce, Christopher (I)/Sorich, Michael/Hustin, Matthew/Lemay, Lewis/Thornton, Kirk/Nakamura, Tatsuhiko/Staley, Steve (II)/Grant, Dougary/McConnohie, Michael/Pinkham, Guy/Kishino, Yukimasa/Ishida, Tarô/Umezu, Hideyuki/Osborne, Jonathan C./Iwata, Mitsuo/Tanaka, Kazumi/Stellrecht, Skip/Kamifuji, Kazuhiro/Spellos, Peter/Pope, Tony/Lee, Peter (I)/Winant, Bruce/Price, Jamieson/Ikemizu, Michihiro/Clarke, Cam/Oliver, Tony (I)/Rae, Ted/Futamata, Issei/Axelrod, Robert/Murray, Ethan/Gurd Jr., Stanley/Ôkura, Masaaki/Romersa, Joe/Walters, Burt/Kramer, Steve (I)/Kitamura, Kôichi/Mercer, Matthew/Bassett, William/Suzuki, Mizuho/Kelso, Lee/Nitta, Sanshirô/Knight, William (III)/Genda, Tesshô/Wimberger, Kurt P./Plantagenet, Richard/Shioya, Kôzô/Hatch, W.T./MacKenzie, Cody/Bergen, Bob/Frierson, Eddie/Itô, Fukue/Phelan, Julie (III)/Brown, Emily (I)/Lane, Marilyn/Ferhardt, Josil/Darro, Bambi/Fujii, Kayoko/Thornton, Chloe/Ôno, Yuka/Goodson, Barbara/Gee, Jessica/Taylor, Julie Anne/Ruff, Michelle/Koyama, Mami/Tissier, Barbara/Cody, Lara/Fuchizaki, Yuriko/Lee, Wendee/Toyoshima, Masami/Ja Lee, Patricia/Forstadt, Rebecca/Tarulli, Lisa/Fox, Sandy (I)/Marshall, Mona (I)/Sarducci, Tony
Aladdin (1992)/Burton, Corey/Cummings, Jim (I)/Young, Philip/Williams, Robin (I)/Welker, Frank/Adler, Charles (I)/Gottfried, Gilbert/Kane, Brad (I)/Proctor, Phil/Gooch, Bruce/Seale, Douglas/Weinger, Scott/Angel, Jack (I)/Wahl, Chris/Houser, Jerry/Freeman, Jonathan (I)/Clarke, Philip L./Pinney, Patrick/Adler, Bruce/McGowan, Mickie/Taylor, Russi/Derryberry, Debi/Lockwood, Vera/Larkin, Linda/Lynn, Sherry (I)/Darling, Jennifer/Zielinski, Kathy/Salonga, Lea
```

Records are basically forward slash(/) separated string containing movie name followed by actor names.

Comment: Can you share a sample from the input file?

Comment: Thanks. I have included two records from the file.

Comment: Just curious, how do you want to use this file after parsing, its structure is title/actor#/actor#/.... You don't have header (of course you can add it) so you will need to use meaningless Column#? This file can be csv, after adding missing separators. But won't be easier to treat this as normal txt file and just read line by line, splitting using separator, then slicing result and treat first element as title, and the remaining list as actors list?

Comment: I am trying to build a SymbolGraph as described here : http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41undirected/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have a problem with your relative path to `movies.csv`. Perhaps it is incorrect, so type provider interprets given path as **sample string** for row type inference. And as your separator is backslash, it ends up deriving row type from `../../movies.csv` being tuple `string*string*string`.

You can either find out what's wrong with your relative path and fix it, or just use the absolute path to your csv file as in the snippet below:

```
    [<Literal>]
    let path = @"your absolute path to csv data file"
    type Movies = CsvProvider<path,"/",.....>
```

Comment: Thanks. With absolute path the code is able to read the entire record. However the file contains 4188 records but the code is successfully  reading only 76 records. If I remove the IgnoreErrors=true option, then the code compilation fails with error : couldn't parse row X with given schema. Expected 43 columns got 36. Looks like having variable length record is not an appropriate dataset for CsvProvider.

Comment: @PawanMishra: This is correct, the expected data set assumes rows having same number of columns with missing values *explicitly* set. For your data to be loaded rows shorter, than the longest one, should be suffixed by proper amount of field separators, like `///////....`, which is a certain headache.